# How can I install Eclipse and Java SDK on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, lwjgl

I have just downloaded Ubuntu. It runs much faster than my Windows XP. But, I don't know how I can set up [Eclipse v4.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Juno), or the Java SDK. I am currently developing in the Lightweight Java Game Library, so I might need some help with that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider installing Sun Java 6 for your Java programming needs; correct me if I'm wrong, but I feel that OpenJDK may still be lacking in some libraries and compatibilities.

If you want to install Java 6 on your machine, you can follow this guide on how to do so: https://codingforme.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/installing-oracle-java-jdk-6-or-7-on-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: I haven't experienced any lacking in functionality/libraries of OpenJDK.  It's my experience that the vast contributors of the open software foundation is usually very much on top of things when it comes to the most important things such as functionality and security.  If you have some bases for your feeling on the flaws with OpenJDK I would be very interested to see it.  For a long time I installed both and used `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to periodically switch between the two to identify which worked best.

Answer (score 14):

Execute this in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-source openjdk-6-demo openjdk-6-doc openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib
```

The first one installs Eclipse (you will be asked to enter your password), and the second one installs all the Java stuff you may need!

Comment: When I execute in my terminal, I get this: E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: @user1551054 did you try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` like it said?

Comment: No, I found a better way! Anyway, I use **NetBeans** now!

Comment: For JDK7 its pretty much the same: **sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-source openjdk-7-demo openjdk-7-doc openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib**

Comment: Should probably install openjdk before eclipse.

Comment: probably for jre, you can use `sudo apt-get install default-jre`. jdk would not be required to run eclipse (unless you would also want to compile eclipse, and so on..). FYR - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get

Answer (score 9):

Don't install Eclipse from the Linux repositories. These repositories may not be up-to-date with the last versions released by Eclipse. A better approach is to follow the instructions in [this answer from Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337281/installing-eclipse-kepler). For Java programming, make sure you have a JDK and a JRE installed

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre
```

You can download whatever Eclipse Java IDE version suits you best from the Eclipse website ([link to the Eclipse v4.4 (Luna) release](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/lunar)).

Comment: Doesn't the JDK also contain the JRE? I think the second part of your command is unnecessary.

Comment: I only installed the JRE and it was enough to run Eclipse 4.5, using `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre`

Answer (score 3):

**Java installation on Ubuntu:**

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

**Eclipse IDE installation on Ubuntu:**

Since it requires a detailed list of steps, I would suggest you to visit the blog post *[Install Eclipse IDE Mars in Linux Ubuntu](http://www.codingalpha.com/install-eclipse-ide-mars-in-linux-ubuntu/)* to check out steps to install Eclipse on Linux Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really install Eclipse - you just download the folder and run the program - just like in windows. Just make sure you download a Linux version.

To install JDK, type:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

You will be asked to type in your password before the installation will begin. You could also install JDK through the software manager.

Comment: to open the browser (or wget - whatever) will be much slower then just type my above command ;) and when you install the package from the ubuntu sources you will be noticed if an update is available and you can install it easily with sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade (will upgrade all packages ;))

Comment: @tuxtimo The version from the repository is usually a number of years older than the version downloaded from eclipse.org.  Currently the apt-get update version is 3.8, 4 years old in the Ubuntu 14.04 repository.  It's easier to get support from the Eclipse community when running a later version.  Everything needed to run Eclipse comes with the downloaded package except for the user's JDK preference which can be installed with the apt-get command provided in this answer.  The latest version as of today is 4.5.

Comment: I know. It's a quiet old post though ... If you really need a newer version it's definitely best to go to the vendor itself.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove all Eclipse packages typing:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse
```

And with <kbd>tab</kbd> find all installed Eclipse packages.

Do the same with Java.

I just reinstalled Eclipse with the command

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

which also contains Java.